# How to bind a text box to listview SelectedItem and to a property

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I've got a short question to you for tonight. I hope it is a simple one. I'm having a `listview` and bound `textboxes`. I mean, when I click on the `listview`, I see the details in the `text boxes` (on the right side of the window).

ListView:

```
ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

Textbox:

```
TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This works pretty nice. But what I'd like to achieve is to update the FirstName in the text box and write it to the database. And this is the point where I'm stuck. How to get the changed FirstName? `SelectedItem` object has just the not changed value.

Could you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Just have a set on SelectedItem.FirstName

Answer (score 0):

By default, `TextBox.Text` property has a `TwoWay` binding, which means both source and target can update it. For the source to update it, if it's not a dependency property but rather a good old .NET property, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event with the event args containing the changed property name. That will correctly update the UI when the source changes.

On the other hand, if you update the source from the UI, it will update the property without issues if it has a setter. So I don't see any problem with your approach.

To write it into a database, you could have a button which, on clicked will take the selected Item and update the database.